# PHP: if defined with an alias is there a way to see how the instance was called?

Tags: php, class, alias

I need a way to see if a instance was created by an alias.

```
class Dummy
{
}

class_alias('Dummy', 'Pipe');

$pipe = new Pipe();
```

This is what I need:

```
echo $pipe->calledWith();

OUTPUT: 'pipe'
```

Comment: Not really, because the instance itself doesn't care how it was created... dirty would be to use a backtrace in the constructor to store that information in a class property.... but why do you need to know this? Sounds like a code smell

Comment: I'm experimenting with alterting spl_autoloader to substitue a class call with the same class but with a wrapper.

Comment: Rather than use an alias, perhaps consider an anonymous class as a wrapper round your Dummy

Comment: I will look into that and come back.